# Passing value from GridView selected value to DropDownList Default Value

Tags: webforms

How do I pass a selected value from GridView to a DropDownList default value.  The DDL always show the first item from the table.  I want to be able to display the first item as the value from another GridView (selected Item).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your DataGridview Event where you get the selected value add.

```
                    //YOur  Bindinding  on Dropdown
                    drpdown.DataSource = //;
                    drpdown.DataTextField = "YourTablecolumn";
                    drpdown.DataBind();

                    string gvalue = //gridselected value;
                    drpdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""+ gvalue +"", "0"));
                    drpdown.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Hope this help.

Regards